# Python: random choice executing all function calls listed

Tags: python, random

I'm stuck on a probably simple issue:
when using choice with functions, it seems like all of them gets executed while only one should.
Example:

```
from ordereddict import OrderedDict
from random import choice

def PrintStrings():
    Text = choice(["Gutentag!", "Ni hao!", "Hola!"])
    print "Chosen Text is:", Text
    return Text

class Greeting():
    fields = OrderedDict([
         ("Morning",     "Hi"),
         ("Afternoon",   "Good Afternoon!"),
         ("Evening",     "Good Evening!"),
    ])

    def change(self):
        self.fields["Morning"] = "Good morning!"

    def changerandom(self, n = 1): 
        function=[
                    {self.fields["Morning"]: PrintStrings()},
                    {self.fields["Afternoon"]: PrintStrings()},
                    {self.fields["Evening"]: PrintStrings()},
                 ]
        result = {}
        for i in range(n):
            result.update(choice(function))
            print "Updated string:",result
            return result

text = Greeting()
text.change()
text.changerandom()
```

When running this script, I get all 3

```
                    {self.fields["Morning"]: PrintStrings()},
                    {self.fields["Afternoon"]: PrintStrings()},
                    {self.fields["Evening"]: PrintStrings()},
```

executed, while it shouldn't.
This script returns:

```
Chosen Text is: Ni hao!
Chosen Text is: Gutentag!
Chosen Text is: Hola!
Updated string: {'Good morning!': 'Hola!'}
```

Expected result is:

```
Chosen Text is: Hola!
Updated string: {'Good morning!': 'Hola!'}
```

Comment: when you write `{self.fields["Morning"]: PrintStrings()}`,  it calls `PrintStrings()`. The entirety of the creation of the `function` list is executed

Comment: BTW -- the variable currently called `Text` should instead be named `text`; see [PEP-8, the Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside some strange data structures choices, you are calling a function in `function`. Remove the parenthesis' to just pass the function as an *object*.

`PrintStrings()` -> `PrintStrings`

Here's a possible solution to get the required output:

```
def changerandom(self, n = 1): 
    result = {}
    for i in range(n):
        key_choice = Greeting.fields[choice(Greeting.fields.keys())]
        result[key_choice] = PrintStrings()
        print "Updated string:", result
        return result
```

With this approach, we grab our random key, and call `PrintStrings()` all in the same iteration.

Comment: Yeah I tried that before, but it prints the object and not the string. I've tried with str(), no luck.
Updated string: {'Good morning!': <function PrintStrings at 0x7f28f7a96d70>}

Comment: @user1473508, what you need to do is *call* the function that you've selected, **after** selecting it. Your original problem is caused by calling it *before* you selected it (which causes even the functions you didn't select to be invoked), the problem you described in your comment above is caused by not calling it at all.

Comment: @Charles I'm not sure to follow.

Comment: @user1473508, whenever `foo()` is evaluated, the code inside the function `foo` is run. So, if you write `f=[ foo(), foo(), foo() ]`, then all three are run *right then*, not later after you pick one and print it. But if you say `f = [foo, foo, foo ]`, then none is run, and you can then later invoke only one of them with `choice(f)()`.

Comment: Ok now it make more sense. However, when I add () after choice it doesn't work as expected: 
    `result.update(choice(function)())`
     `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: Charles Duffy is right, updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: @user1473508, that's because your return value isn't a function, it's a dictionary that contains a function. You can't execute the dictionary, you can only execute the function -- so you need to pick that function out and execute it.

Comment: @user1473508, ...now, if you had an actual good reason to be doing it this way (not picking a function, but picking a dictionary where the function is a member; and not printing just the return value, but printing the whole dictionary with the intent that the return value be substituted), then it would be possible to write an answer that accomodated that, but you certainly haven't shown anything that would indicate that this structure is sensible, and thus that it doesn't make more sense to just abandon it.

Comment: @Charles, yes sorry about that, the actual structure is an example, but I need to keep the original format.
The changerandom function is important and I actually have several functions in it, like:
                    `{self.fields["Morning"]: PrintALLStrings},`
                    `{self.fields["Afternoon"]: PrintPostStrings},`
                    `{self.fields["Evening"]: PrintPreStrings},`
All I need is being able to call the chosen function  at this point:
`result.update(choice(function))`

Comment: @user1473508, ...frankly, that format doesn't make much sense to me. Why wouldn't it be something like `{"time": "Morning", "func": PrintAllStrings}`, `{"time": "Afternoon", "func": PrintPostStrings}`, etc? I mean, if you're only going to have one key and one value to a structure, it might as well just be a tuple.

Comment: @Charles, Yes that would work for me! Any example with the code I provided?

Comment: If you used the dictionaries I gave above, `result_printable = dict(result); result_printable.pop('func'); result_printable['output']  = result['func'](); print result_printable` would print something like `{"time": "Morning", "output": "PrintAllStrings Output Here"}`. That goes out of its way to avoid side effects; it could be shorter under some circumstances.

Comment: Ok! Can you add it to your response so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An object will give you a means to run code only on serialization, not on instantiation:

```
class PrintStrings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = None
    def __str__(self):
        if self.text is None:
            text = choice(["Gutentag!", "Ni hao!", "Hola!"])
            print "Chosen Text is:", text
        return text
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

The rest of your code can be used as-is, with this class replacing your `PrintStrings` function.